# Why LLVM 3.8 Package is Installed on two different directories in ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: cmake, llvm, ubuntu-16.04

I am a windows user and this the first time I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to build LLVM pass using cmake .. command exactly as described at https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asampson/blog/llvm.html. So I installed LLVM 3.8 using sudo apt-get install llvm from ubuntu terminal. When I see the system directories I realized that only cmake directory of LLVM installation is at /usr/share/llvm-3.8/cmake while the rest of LLVM directories (bin, build, include, lib, libexec, share) are at /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/ . . . Problem occurs when certain files like LLVMExports.cmake of cmake directory uses following statement
get_filename_component(_realOrig "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/share/llvm-3.8/cmake" REALPATH)

My point is I dont have /usr/lib/llvm-3.8/share/llvm3.8/cmake directory. Is there any problem with my installation of LLVM package?

Comment: What are you **trying** to do? The packaging should be fine.

Comment: I am using cmake .. command to build an LLVM pass. CMakeLists.txt file uses find_package (LLVM Required Config) statement therefore /usr/share/llvm-3.8/cmake directory files (LLVMConfig.cmake & LLVMExports.cmake) are called. But these files refere to paths which are incorrect like I mentioned in the above question. I want to confirm if someone else has installed llvm package on ubuntu 16.04 then plz tell me where llvm related directories/files reside on their machine? Thanks

Comment: This is no problem. `find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)` works fine on my machine.

Comment: which versions of llvm and ubuntu are you using?